# AWS Mobile Analytics Unity SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-mobile-analytics

Does anyone know of a Unity SDK for AWS Mobile Analytics?

Has anyone had success integrating AWS Mobile Analyics & a Unity application?

There is sparse information about the service and the support email is extremely slow to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they have just released the Unity SDK for Mobile Analytics.

http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E8EFREHR4JV8/Announcing-Amazon-Mobile-Analytics-in-the-AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-Unity

Shameless Copy:

```
void Start()
{

       _analyticsManager = AmazonMobileAnalyticsManager.GetOrCreateInstance(
                new CognitoAWSCredentials(<cognitoIdentityPoolId>, <region>), 
                <region>, 
                <appId>);       
}
```

And a monetization event:

```
AmazonMobileAnalyticsMonetizationEvent monetizationEvent = new AmazonMobileAnalyticsMonetizationEvent();

monetizationEvent.Quantity = 3.0;
monetizationEvent.ItemPrice = 1.99;
monetizationEvent.ProductId = "health_booster";
monetizationEvent.ItemPriceFormatted = "$1.99";
monetizationEvent.Store = "Apple";
monetizationEvent.TransactionId = "TransactionId123";
monetizationEvent.Currency = "USD";

_analyticsManager.RecordEvent(monetizationEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

On December 17th, 2014 AWS announced the following Unity SDK, unfortunately it does not yet interface with AWS Mobile Analytics - so only the native iOS & Android SDKs can currently be used.

http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1KVR26DO9H5VX/Announcing-AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-Unity-Developer-Preview

Comment: Per that blog, the Unity SDK does not yet interface with the Mobile Analytics Service